# Split array into key => array()

Tags: php

Consider the following array:

```
$array[23] = array(
  [0] => 'FOO'
  [1] => 'BAR'
  [2] => 'BAZ'
);
```

Whenever I want to work with the inner array, I do something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
  foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo $value;
  }
}
```

The outer foreach-loop is there to split the $key and $value-pairs of $array. This works fine for arrays with many keys ([23], [24], ...)but seems redundant **if you know beforehand that $array only has one key** (23 in this case). In a case as such, isn't there a better way to split the key from the values? Something like

```
split($array into $key => $values)
foreach ($values as $value) {
  echo $value;
}
```

I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`reset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) returns the first element of you array and [`key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) returns its key:

```
$your_inner_arr = reset($array);
$your_key = key($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yea, just get rid of your first foreach and define the array you're using with the known $key of your outter array.

```
foreach ($array[23] as $key =>$val):
   //do whatever you want in here
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

If an array has only one element, you can get it with [`reset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php):

```
$ar = array(23 => array('foo', 'bar'));
$firstElement = reset($ar);
```

Answer (score 0):

A very succinct approach would be

```
foreach(array_shift($array) as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```